# Finding limit using Riemann integral problem

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, riemann-integration

How do I evaluate the following limits ?

$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(2k-1\right) \sqrt[n]{e^{2k-1}}\right)$$

In this case I'm confused about function to integrate: $f\left(x\right)=\:x\cdot e^x  ?$
Please help and explain to understand how I find the function to integrate...

$$\lim _{n\to \infty }\frac{1}{n^2}\cdot \sqrt[n]{\left(n^2+1\right)\cdot \left(n^2+2\right)\cdot \left(n^2+5\right)\cdot \:\:\:...\:\:\:\cdot \left(2n^2-2n+2\right)}$$

Answer (score 1):

Your sum can be written

$$e^{-1/n}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{2k}{n} e^{2k/n}\right) - \frac{e^{-1/n}}{n}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k = 1}^n e^{2k/n}\right).$$

In the first term, the expression in parentheses is a Riemann sum of $2xe^{2x}$ over $[0,1]$. So it converges to

$$\int_0^1 2xe^{2x}\, dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^2 ue^u\, du = \frac{1}{2}(u - 1)e^u\bigg|_{u = 0}^2 = \frac{1}{2}(1 + e^2).$$

Since $e^{-1/n} \to 1$, it follows that the first term converges to $\frac{1}{2}(1 + e^2)$. In the second term, the expression in parentheses is a Riemann sum of $e^{2x}$ over $[0,1]$. So it converges (to $\int_0^1 e^{2x}\, dx$). Since $e^{-1/n} \to 1$ and $1/n \to 0$, it follows that the second term converges to $0$. Therefore, your limit is $\frac{1}{2}(1 + e^2)$.

Comment: But that is not equal with this   $\lim _{n\to \infty }\sum _{k=1}^n\left(\frac{\left(2k-1\right)}{n}\cdot e^{\frac{\left(2k-1\right)}{n}}\right)$   ?

Comment: In your first formula, I think it is $2k/n-1/n$, (and so you have to split the formula in two parts)

Comment: @Andrei sorry, misread. I will make changes.

Comment: @Andrei I've made the appropriate edits, assuming I haven't misread anything. :)

Comment: but I don't understand why is $$2x\cdot e^{2x}$$ and not $$x\cdot e^x$$ ? because I think $$\frac{\left(2k-1\right)}{n}$$ equal with x in our function

Comment: @Andrei the points $k/n$, $1 \le k \le n$ partition $[0,1]$ into $n$ subintervals of length $1/n$. The sum you speak of is of the form $(1/n)\sum_{k = 1}^n f(k/n)$, where $f(x) = 2xe^{2x}$.

Comment: but how you find a function in general case, because I can't understand that thing to don't make a mistake to confuse $$x\cdot e^x\:with\:2x\cdot e^{2x}?$$

Comment: @Andrei let's consider the sum in parentheses in the first term. Inside the sum, we have $(2k/n)e^{2k/n}$, and we want to recognize this as $f(k/n)$ for some function $f$. If we have $f(k/n) = (2k/n)e^{2k/n}$ and we replace $k/n$ with $x$, what would $f(x)$ be?

Comment: yes, that I understand but in some cases that method don't work like a second limit

Comment: @Andrei these things take practice. You can't always evaluate a sum using Riemann integrals. Your second limit problem is much more intricate than the initial problem, and should be posted as a new question. If I'm not mistaken, you don't need to resort to integration to compute the limit.

Comment: You've right, at the second limit $$e^{\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum _{k=1}^n\:\left(1+\frac{\left(k^2-2k+2\right)}{n^2}\right)\right)}\:,\:in\:this\:case\:when\:we\:calculate\:exponent,\:which\:will\:be\:the\:function\:at\:the\:exponent\:and\:why?$$     $$how\:we\:see\:\frac{\left(k^2-2k+2\right)}{n^2}\:like\:a\:function?\:f\:\left(x\right)=1+\:?\:\:...$$

Comment: f(x)=ln(1 + ?), 1 + what and why?